# How to pass preventDefault call to other event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

When the event occurs, some other event is triggered by its name. In some cases the second handler can call `preventDefault`. How to pass this call to original event?

https://jsfiddle.net/edgv8qur/1/

```js
$("button").click(function (event) {
  $("body").trigger("some-custom-event");

  // If the custom event was prevented, prevent original one too
  if (true) { // How to check?
    event.preventDefault();
  }
})

$("body").on("some-custom-event", function (event) {
  if (Math.random() > .5) {
    console.log("prevent");
    event.preventDefault();
  } else {
    console.log("allow");
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Test</button>
```

PS: [Same question in Russian.](//ru.stackoverflow.com/q/505626/178988)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass an array of arguments to `trigger()` which will be passed to the event handler set in `on()`. Here is how you do it:

```
$("button").click(function (event) {
    function cb(prevent) {
        // If the custom event was prevented, prevent original one too
        if (prevent) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    }
    $("body").trigger("some-custom-event", [cb]);
})

$("body").on("some-custom-event", function (event, cb) {
  if (Math.random() > .5) {
    console.log("prevent");
    event.preventDefault();
    cb(true);
  } else {
    console.log("allow");
  }
})
```

You can find out more about `trigger()` [here](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/).

**UPDATE:**

If you dont want to edit the handlers this is the way to go:

```
$("button").click(function (event) {
    var event = jQuery.Event('some-custom-event');
    $("body").trigger(event);

    if (event.isDefaultPrevented()) {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log("Prevented");
    } else {
        console.log("Allowed");
    }
})

$("body").on("some-custom-event", function (event) {
    if (Math.random() > .5) {
        console.log("prevent");
        event.preventDefault();
    } else {
        console.log("allow");
    }
})
```

[`event.isDefaultPrevented()`](https://api.jquery.com/event.isDefaultPrevented/) Returns whether event.preventDefault() was ever called on this event object.

Comment: I do not want to modify handlers of second event.

Comment: If I modify the handler, I'll just pass original event to it. Why do I need callback?

Comment: What if I have event namespace?

Comment: [Yes](//jsfiddle.net/edgv8qur/4/). I should've use jQuery 1.8 in my tests. Dispatch like `.smth` doesn't vork in jQuery 1.12 at all, not just passing to the event.